# Git asking for git@git.repo.local password

Tags: git, bash, ssh, passwords, gitlab

I'm trying to clone or push to an empty repository on our Gitlab server using SSH authentication but whenever I try I am asked for the git password (using Git Bash):

```
myname@PC0016 MINGW64 /c/users/myname/dev
$ git clone git@git.repo.local:android/myApp.git
Cloning into 'myApp'...
git@git.repo.local's password:
```

I have tried my password and the Git password given to me by an admin but I get:

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Why do I need to supply this password when I have added my SSH key to the project file in Gitlab? What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: where do you have your key?

Comment: I'm not certain that the password is the problem.  The Git provider has to recognize and approve of your public cert.

Comment: @Jakuje My key is in C:\Users\myname\.ssh

Comment: `ssh -Tvvv git@git.repo.local` does ask for a password? Lists the key you are trying to use?

Comment: @Jakuje It does, strangely it is looking in the Z: drive... `debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /z/.ssh/id_rsa type -1` ... Am I able to point this to my .ssh folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ssh_config`, where you will point your client to your identity file:

```
Host git.repo.local
  IdentityFile C:\Users\myname\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Also store this file in the `/z/.ssh/config` to be read by your client.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it may solve it. I have an ssh_config file in C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh - do I need to add this in there with the list of hosts?

Comment: Yes, you can add it also there. It should do the job. The `Host` line is not needed if you want to use this identity file everywhere.

Comment: Perfect, I am now able to clone and push! Thanks very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need an ssh key to skip the authentication phase.
Usually the operation that I perform are:

1. Generate an ssh key if you don't have already one: [instructions](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README),
2. Add the key to gitlab: [page](https://gitlab.com/profile/keys),
3. Clone the repository via ssh: *Clone or downloading* button in the project main page,
4. Set the username or the email address for the commit messages: [instructions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup),
5. Have fun!!!

If you properly set the key everything will be fine.

Comment: The question seemed to mention Gitlab, not GitHub, but yes I suspect the issue is that GitLab is not recognizing the cert.

Comment: @petehallw Having an SSH key means nothing if you haven't told GitLab about it.  This would be like having an invitation to a party without an ID to prove who you are.  You would never let such a person in.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added my SSH key to GitLab as mentioned in the description. I think the issue is where it is looking on my local machine.

Comment: There are _two_ places where the key needs to be present, on your local machine _and_ on the GitLab server.  Are you certain it is present in both places?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned both. The issue has now been solved, thanks for your comments.